# QGIS and PostgreSQL sharded tables

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS with a connection to a PostgreSQL DB with PostGIS. On that DB we have some sharded tables with geography columns. The problem is that I can not see those tables in the browser of QGIS. I do see others tables that are not sharded.

Does anyone have an idea of a possible solution?

Comment: How did you create your shard tables ? It seems that you can use Citus extension (https://blog.dbi-services.com/sharding-with-postgresql/) or postgres_fdw extension (https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/24/an-overview-of-sharding-in-postgresql-and-how-it-relates-to-mongodbs/)
Maybe one of them works better with Qgis ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not the DBA so I can not decide with extension to use. I know that the extension they use is Citus. Maybe if the DBA change to use a different extension it fix my problem, but unfortunately is not my call. I was able to find a workaround, I used the DB Manager to create a layer from a query to those tables. But still I can not see the tables in the browser of QGIS.  Thank you